# Trying to create a dictionary from a list of numbers, but list index is out of range

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to make a function that creates a dictionary with number of occurrences being the keys and each key having a list of numbers that occurred that many times as values

The part where it messes up is at the line:

```
if num_list[i] not in num_dic.values():
```

or also messes up at:

```
if num_list.index(i) == num_list.index(j):
```

## function below creates a dictionary from num_list

```
def createDic(num_list):
    num_dic = {}
    num_occurs = 0
    for i in num_list:
        if num_list[i] not in num_dic.values():
            for j in num_list:
                if num_list.index(i) == num_list.index(j):
                    num_occurs += 1
            num_dic[num_occurs].append(num_list[i])
        num_occurs = 0
    return num_dic
```

Comment: Passing in a list of [1, 2, 3, 2, 1] returns a `KeyError: 2` at `num_dic[num_occurs].append(num_list[i])`; when you say your code 'messes up' at `if num_list.index(i) == num_list.index(j):`, what error does it return?

Comment: It returns: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ok cool. And what are you passing in to your function to produce the IndexError?

Comment: When you have `for i in num_list:` `i` is not an index in the list, it's a member of the list.

Comment: I got an IndexError when I used [5, 6, 7, 5]

Comment: Right, because `num_list[5]`, `num_list[6]`, and `num_list[7]` are all IndexErrors.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a Python Plebian XD....rookie mistake

Comment: @benthediver99 you might find `num_list.count(i)` really useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this differently, first count the occurences, then convert that to the dict:

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4]
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> c = Counter(a)
>>> c
Counter({4: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1})
>>> occurences = defaultdict(list)
>>> for a,b in c.items() :
...     occurences[b].append(a)
... 
>>> occurences
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [2, 3], 2: [1], 3: [4]})
>>> dict(occurences)
{1: [2, 3], 2: [1], 3: [4]}
```

Comment: Hey lenik - can you explain the use of `defaultdict` here? What's the reason for using this over a python standard dictionary?

Comment: @PeptideWitch `defaultdict` helps you with checking if this key is already added to the dict, automatically creating the `list` for every new value.

Comment: That's handy. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

```py
data = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"]
info = {}

for i in data:
    count = data.count(i)

    if count not in info:
        info[count] = [i]
    elif i not in info[count]:
        info[count].extend(i)

print(info)
```

Outputs:

```
{1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], 3: ['c', 'd']}
```

---

A better solution, but uses an import:

```py
from collections import Counter

data = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"]
info = {}

for o, c in Counter(data).items():
    info[c] = [o] if c not in info else info[c] + [o]

print(info)
```

Outputs:

```
{1: ['a'], 2: ['b'], 3: ['c', 'd']}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This is an inefficient implementation, it's O(n^2), you can solve it in O(n)
2. You didn't initialize `num_dict`, you can use defaultdict:

   num_dict = defaultdict(list)
3. `num_list[i]` will not be in `num_dict.values()` because the `values()` are lists and `num_list[i]` is an integer (you assume)
4. You iterate over the list with `i` but then think it's the index rather than the values in the list, you should replace it with `for i in range(len(num_list))` (same for j)